# Resize text acording to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different elements in my html with different text sizes. I want to set them to be dynamic so that it would show different font sizes for different screen sizes.

What would be the best way?
Now I am doing it like this but it makes the code look ugly:

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function(){
$('#first').css('font-size',($(window).width()*0.2)+'px');
$('h2').css('font-size',($(window).width()*0.02)+'px');
$('h1').css('font-size',($(window).width()*0.03)+'px');
```

For two elements it would be ok, but I have many more. Don't have big experience with html/css/javascript so this was what I came up with.

Since I am learning I want to know what would be the best way.

Maybe you have some suggestions how to improve that?

Comment: You could use `$("*")` to select everything, but I'd strongly recommend using a screen-size-relative unit, like `em` instead, then it's purely CSS based.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the new css units vw,vh (viewport width/height) for this.

Here's an interesting [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) which shows you how to use them for typography.

Example: (from above article)

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

So h1 will have font-size 5.9% of the viewport width. etc.

---

That being said, using viewport units for `font-size` in the above way is problematic because when the viewport width is very narrow - then the rendered font size will become too small and vice-versa.

In order to overcome this problem, I can recommend using a technique called [Fluid Type](https://madebymike.com.au/writing/precise-control-responsive-typography/) AKA [CSS Locks](http://blog.typekit.com/2016/08/17/flexible-typography-with-css-locks/).

> A CSS lock is a specific kind of CSS value calculation where:
>
> - there is a minimum value and a maximum value,
> - and two breakpoints    (usually based on the viewport width),
> - and between those breakpoints,    the actual value goes linearly from the minimum to the maximum.

([From this article on CSS locks](https://fvsch.com/code/css-locks/) which also explains the math involved in great detail.)

So let's say we want to apply the above technique such that the minimum font-size is 16px at a viewport width of 600px or less, and will increase linearly until it reaches a maximum of 32px at a viewport width of 1200px.

We could use [this SASS mixin](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7f22e44ace49b5124eec) which does all of the math for us so that the CSS would look something like this:

```
div {
  /* linearly increase the font-size from 16->32px 
     between a viewport width of 600px-> 1200px  */
  @include fluid-type(font-size, 600px, 1200px, 16px, 32px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div {
     font-size: 16px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  div {
     font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

```css
// ----
// libsass (v3.3.6)
// ----

// =========================================================================
//
//  PRECISE CONTROL OVER RESPONSIVE TYPOGRAPHY FOR SASS
//  ---------------------------------------------------
//  Indrek Paas @indrekpaas
//
//  Inspired by Mike Riethmuller's Precise control over responsive typography
//  http://madebymike.com.au/writing/precise-control-responsive-typography/
//
//  `strip-unit()` function by Hugo Giraudel
//  
//  11.08.2016 Remove redundant `&` self-reference
//  31.03.2016 Remove redundant parenthesis from output
//  02.10.2015 Add support for multiple properties
//  24.04.2015 Initial release
//
// =========================================================================

@function strip-unit($value) {
  @return $value / ($value * 0 + 1);
}

@mixin fluid-type($properties, $min-vw, $max-vw, $min-value, $max-value) {
  @each $property in $properties {
    #{$property}: $min-value;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $min-vw) {
    @each $property in $properties {
      #{$property}: calc(#{$min-value} + #{strip-unit($max-value - $min-value)} * (100vw - #{$min-vw}) / #{strip-unit($max-vw - $min-vw)});
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $max-vw) {
    @each $property in $properties {
      #{$property}: $max-value;
    }
  }
}

// Usage:
// ======

// /* Single property */
// html {
//   @include fluid-type(font-size, 320px, 1366px, 14px, 18px);
// }

// /* Multiple properties with same values */
// h1 {
//   @include fluid-type(padding-bottom padding-top, 20em, 70em, 2em, 4em);
// }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

div {
  @include fluid-type(font-size, 600px, 1200px, 16px, 32px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div {
     font-size: 16px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  div {
     font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Responsive Typography technique known as Fluid Type or CSS Locks. 
  Resize the browser window to see the effect.
</div>
```

### [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/zdPrWz)

---

### Further Reading

[Precise control over responsive typography](https://madebymike.com.au/writing/precise-control-responsive-typography/)

[Fluid Responsive Typography With CSS Poly Fluid Sizing](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/05/fluid-responsive-typography-css-poly-fluid-sizing/)

[Non-linear interpolation in CSS](https://madebymike.com.au/writing/non-linear-interpolation-in-css/)

Answer (score 5):

use media for set font size in css file

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    body {
        font-size: 10px;
    };
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    body {
        font-size: 11px;
    };
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    body {
        font-size: 12px;
    };
}

@media(min-width:1200px) {
    body {
        font-size: 13px;
    };
}
```

Comment: So, the cool part of this answer is that make you feel smart as hell `lol` with all those `@media` but, `vw` is the right answer in 2016..still +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

ditch javascript to change the font-sizes...specify font-size in em in your css files like this.

```
div{
   font-size:2em;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this provides what is sought by the original question. It would only resize the text if the container (or one of its parents) changes the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pixels, use `em` because it will scale accordingly.

**From Wikipedia:**

> Online, the use of the em measurement has become more common; with the development of Cascading Style Sheets (or CSS), the W3C best practices recommendations within HTML and online markup now call for web pages to be based on scalable designs, using a relative unit of measurement (such as the em measurement), rather than a fixed one such as pixels ("px") or points.

- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29)
- [w3](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm)

Comment: how about using vw? Would it be recomended, because it isn't supported in most of the browsers

Answer (score 0):

Do not use javascript to specify font sizes. CSS has built in methods for that.

You can use 'em' or '%' with the font size to change the size of font related to your page and devices dimensions.

Code Example:

```
font-size: 3em;
font-size: 10%;
```

Both shall do.

Comment: This won't help you when you resize your browser.

Comment: @ArunAravind Screen Size never meant browser window size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it helps (if you are intent on using javascript)
http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Browser will set its font sizes accordingly if you set in `%` or `em` basis.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with css media query.

Inside the media query set body size in percentage.

eg: css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   body {
      font-size: 90%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
   body {
      font-size: 100%;
   }
}
```

Then set font-sizes on each and every elements you want to resize font while resizing browser or according to resolution in percentage.

eg: if you want to resize fonts on h1

```
h1 {
   font-size: 150%;
}
```

it will work as you want it to.

Comment: Don't set font-sizes in em as variations in em's are exponential. Use percentage instead.

Comment: Would you recomend to use vw? It resaizes also on browser change but it's not fully supported in all browsers and a bit buggy in chrome

Comment: Now is that a library? I don't know, But you are better off with media query. Try it and see the magic yourself.

Comment: That's what i said i haven't used it yet. I am not a web developer. You experiment with this and let me go and read the document you just gave link to. Thanx :)

Comment: There itself it is written that it is getting ready to be shipped with chrome 20 .. So browser support is not there yet i guess. If browser support is there you should use it defnitely. But they report that there are certain bugs that might haven't been fixed.

Comment: I think I will stick with the vw because it resizes also on browser change

Comment: Before that check for browser support and bugs

Answer (score 0):

Sizing-resizing of fonts using JavaScript is not a good practice. Better do it traditionally using CSS. You can size your fonts in CSS with different units like px, em and % and rem (root em).

In order to get your fonts sized according to the screen size, set the font-sizes in rem. Or make use of media queries to set font-sizes for different screen resolutions. Here are some sample media queries to do so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #first { font-size: 204px; }
    h2 { font-size: 20px; }
    h1 { font-size: 30px; }
}
```